# how to delete duplicates from a database table based on a certain field

Tags: sql, database-design

i have a table that somehow got duplicated.  i basically want to delete all records that are duplicates, which is defined by a field in my table called SourceId.  There should only be one record for each source ID.

is there any SQL that i can write that will delete every duplicate so i only have one record per Sourceid ?

Comment: Any particular version of SQL you're referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a column ID that can tie-break the duplicate sourceid's, you can use this.  Using `min(id)` causes it to keep just the min(id) per sourceid batch.

```
delete from tbl
where id NOT in
(
select  min(id)
from tbl
group by sourceid
)
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  an id could appear in the subquery if it's the min(id) from some other sourceid.  I think you need a correlated subquery to be only the min(id) you are looking for.

Comment: @Walter the assumption here is that ID is unique across the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from table
where pk in (
select i2.pk
from table i1
  inner join table i2
   on i1.SourceId = i2.SourceId
)
```

good practice is to start with 
`select * from …` and only later replace to `delete from …`